# stack implementation in python, how does the index location work and how do I check if stack is empty?

Tags: stack

I'm a bit stuck getting my head around the stacks algorithm. 
The pseudocode for a stack algorithm is:

1. check to see if stack is full.
2. If the stack is full report an error.
3. increment stack pointer.
4. insert new data item into cell pointed to by the stack pointer and stop.

1) I always thought that a list or an array starts at 0. If we are incrementing the stack pointer before adding a data item, then how do we start off by adding the very first data item if the stack pointer always starts at 0 and the first item should go into to index 0 - but if we increment before adding then doesn't it go into 1 and leave index 0 empty?

2) When I've looked at the actual code implemented in python it looks like this: is it required in my code to check if stack is full and report an error. Why in the code are we not incrementing a stack pointer?

3) How do I generate an error in my pop function, such that if my stack is empty it says stack is empty?

```
stack = []

def view():
        for x in range (len(stack)):
            print(stack[x])
def push():
    item = input("Please enter the  item you wishto add to the stack: ")
    stack.append(item)

def pop():
    if stack < 0:
        print ("stack is empty")
    else:
        item = stack.pop(-1)
        print ("you just popped out: ", item)

while True:
    print ("")
    print("Python implementation of a stack")
    print("********************************")
    print("1. view Stack")
    print("2. Push onto Stack")
    print("3. Pop out of Stack")
    print("********************************")
    print("")
    menu_choice = int (input("Please enter your menu choice: "))
    print ("")
    print ("")

    if menu_choice == 1:
        view()
    elif menu_choice == 2:
        push()
    elif menu_choice == 3:
        pop()
```

Comment: If you have multiple questions, you should isolate them and ask them separately. Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: but they all refer to this code

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to answer broad questions like this, but hopefully this will be helpful to you:

1) Note that your condition for whether a stack is 'empty' is whether or not the pointer is less than 0: `if stack < 0`. This suggests that you start your stack pointer at `-1` and, when you add an item, increment it to `0` such that the first item is put into the 'zero' box. However, it would be valid to change the order of your checking, if you similarly altered the rest of your algorithm to account for this.

2) The code you're referencing isn't included in the question? The code at the bottom of your question is clearly wrong. Regardless, you should be incrementing a stack pointer if and only if the 'top' of the stack is moving, and you should be checking that the new location is valid.

3) Typically in Python you want to 'raise' an appropriate exception. You can use one of [the standard ones](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) or create your own. An `IndexError` would be appropriate here.

Overall, you want something more like this (note: untested!):

```
def class Stack:
    stack_ptr = -1
    stack = []
    max_length = 10

    def push(self, item):
        if stack_ptr < max_length:
            stack[stack_ptr] = item
            stack_ptr = stack_ptr + 1
        else:
            raise IndexError("Maximum stack length reached!")

    def pop(self):
        if stack_ptr < 0:  # Need to refer to the pointer, not the stack
            raise IndexError("Stack is empty!")
        else:
            item = stack[stack_ptr)  # get item
            stack_ptr = stack_ptr - 1  # Decrement pointer
            return item

    def manipulate_stack(self):
        while True:
            print_options()  # Put all the printing mishagus in it's own function
            menu_choice = int (input("Please enter your menu choice: "))
            print("")
            print("")

            if menu_choice == 1:
                view()  # unimplemented
            elif menu_choice == 2:
                try:
                    item = input("Please enter the  item you wish to add to the stack: ")
                    push(item)
                except IndexError:
                    print("The stack is full! You cannot add an item.")
            elif menu_choice == 3:
                try:
                    item = pop()
                    print("You have popped item={}".format(item))
                except IndexError:  # Handle it when something goes wrong
                    print("The stack is empty. You cannot pop!")

stack = Stack()
stack.manipulate_stack()
```

Comment: in question 2 i'm referring to the code at the bottom of 3).

Comment: That code is clearly wrong. You can't have `stack < 0` if `stack` is an array.

Comment: 3) is it possible that instead of an index irror i can return a print statement to the user like "you have tried to pop from an empty list". if so how can i do this?

Comment: @lisaturner I've updated the sample code to show a better way of structuring it (though it's untested). Note that error handling should not be in the same place as the function attempt. You should also separate out input/output from direct stack manipulation.